# Jquery UI sortable event params not work as documented

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am implemented a jQuery UI [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) element.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                stop: function(event, ui)
                {
                    alert('pos:' + ui.position);
                    alert(ui.offset);
                }
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

The sorting is working. According to the documentation the the **ui** parameters in events will have several properties (e.g. ui.position, ui.offset, etc.)

When I alert these they are all returning `[object Object]`

I am trying to figure out what position was moved. (i.e. position 5 is now position 3) So I can save the new positions in a DB.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, I'd suggest you look into [serialize()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Sortable#method-serialize). It may allow you to persist the position data more easily.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks, I think thats what I really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These parameters are objects, not strings.
`alert`ing them calls `toString()`, which returns `"[object Object]"`.

You can see what is in the objects by `console.log`ing them instead.

Comment: +1 I never even knew about console.log I will be using that a lot! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

position has two properties you might actually be looking for `postion.left` and `position.top` this also goes for `offset` as well.